# PC XNA Development

Tags: xna, game-engine

I first interacted with XNA a few years ago when it had support for both PC and Xbox developing.
Now i see that the directions of development are Xbox and Windows Phone. Is the PC part gone or is it automatically included into the Xbox development.
We want to develop a game for PC only. Do I have enough support for it or the newest version of XNA shut it down?

Comment: XNA is not supported in Windows 8 metro mode and it definitely looks like Microsoft is in the process of sunsetting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone stuff got split off from the Xbox 360 stuff, due to Windows 8 and particularly Windows Phone 8 coming. In the process, Microsoft made a real mess of the [create.msdn.com](http://create.msdn.com/) website.

The PC stuff (and some of the WP7 stuff) for XNA is still in with the Xbox stuff.

The latest version of XNA is 4.0. It still "works". I'm making a PC game using it. On the PC you can basically think of it as a really nice C# wrapper for DirectX 9 (plus a content pipeline). It works on the Desktop in Windows 8, but not in the new Metro-style UI.

Microsoft have been showing very, very little love for XNA since it started to show off Windows 8. They have said *precisely nothing* about the future of XNA. Maybe there will be a new version for the next Xbox. Or maybe 4.0 will be the last version. I don't think anyone outside Microsoft knows.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to develop for Windows 8 also, then I would suggest looking into the [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) project. Here is a snippet from their website:

> MonoGame is an Open Source implementation of the Microsoft XNA 4
>   Framework. Our goal is to allow XNA developers on Xbox 360, Windows &
>   Windows Phone to port their games to the iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux
>   and Windows 8 Metro.  PlayStation Mobile development is currently in
>   progress.

The develop3d branch is the branch you would want to look into. It's still in dev, but there have been quite a few games that use it.

As the above stated, Microsoft has been pretty tight lipped about the future of XNA. Here is a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobfamiliar/archive/2012/08/01/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-1-overview.aspx) to a article series about porting XNA to monogame